# Как применить кастомный стиль CSS к элементу SVG <use>?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-selectors

Я работаю с элементом svg

```js
var defsElement = document.querySelector('defs');
var defsElementX = defsElement.getBBox().x;
var defsElementY = defsElement.getBBox().y;

var colX = [];


for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (i == 0) ? colX.push(25): colX.push(colX[i - 1] + 60)
};
//console.log(colX);

const y = 145;

const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

colX.forEach(
    (a, i) => {
        let useEl = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'use');
        useEl.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', "xlink:href", "#stick man");
        useEl.setAttribute("class", "use" + [i]);
        useEl.setAttribute("id", "id" + [i]);
        useEl.setAttribute("x", `${a}`);
        useEl.setAttribute("y", `${y}`);
        svg.appendChild(useEl);
    }
)
```

```css
.stickman {
    stroke: red;
    fill: none;
}

.stickman>.head {
    fill: black;
    stroke: blue;
}

.head {
    fill: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    <svg id="layer" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <defs>

            <g id="stick man" style="fill: none; stroke: black;">
            <circle class="head" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
            <line class="body" x1="10" y1="20" x2="10" y2="44"/>
            <polyline class="upper" points="1 58, 10 44, 19 58"/>
            <polyline class="lower" points="1 24, 10 30, 19 24"/>
            </g>
            </defs>

            <g class="stickman" id="stickman" transform = "translate (85,50)">
                <circle class="head" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
                <line class="body" x1="10" y1="20" x2="10" y2="44"/>
                <polyline class="upper" points="1 58, 10 44, 19 58"/>
                <polyline class="lower" points="1 24, 10 30, 19 24"/>
    
    <script href="index.js"></script>

    
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Я хочу научиться применять стили CSS к другому элементу `<use></use>`.
Например, как я могу применить 3 разных цвета для заливки каждой головы.
Какой селектор CSS следует использовать?

я пытался так:

```
.use0>.head {
    fill: brown;
}
```

JavaScript генерирует это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to apply custom CSS style on SVG  element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71430260/7394871) от участника  [@smpa01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11156131/smpa01).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/71430260/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Для этого вы можете использовать переменные CSS:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  let useEl = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'use');
  useEl.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', "xlink:href", "#stickRef");
  useEl.setAttribute("id", `id${i}`);
  useEl.setAttribute("x", (i * 60) + 25);
  useEl.setAttribute("y", 25);
  svg.appendChild(useEl);
}
```

```css
#id0 { --head-colour: #F00; --line-colour: #900; }
#id1 { --head-colour: #0F0; --line-colour: #090; }
#id2 { --head-colour: #00F; --line-colour: #009; }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="stickRef" style="fill: none; stroke: var(--line-colour);">
      <circle class="head" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" style="fill: var(--head-colour)" />
      <line class="body" x1="10" y1="20" x2="10" y2="44"/>
      <polyline class="upper" points="1 58, 10 44, 19 58"/>
      <polyline class="lower" points="1 24, 10 30, 19 24"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71431144/7394871) от участника  [@Mike D Sutton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8695156/mike-d-sutton).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обернуть группу с помощью `<g>` и присвоить группе  `style="fill: none;"` - закраска только линии и `<polyline>` человечка-палки, оставляя круг с неопределенной заливкой.

Теперь вы можете установить атрибут заливки или придать стиль элементу `<use>`. Заливка будет применена только к кругу.

```css
use{fill:red}
use:nth-of-type(2){fill:gold}
use:nth-of-type(3){fill:blue}
```

```html
<svg id="layer" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 100 500 500">
  <defs>
    <g id="stickman" style="stroke: black;">
      <circle class="head" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"></circle>
      <g style="fill: none;">
      <line class="body" x1="10" y1="20" x2="10" y2="44"></line>
      <polyline class="upper" points="1 58, 10 44, 19 58"></polyline>
      <polyline class="lower" points="1 24, 10 30, 19 24"></polyline>
      </g>
    </g>
  </defs>


  <use xlink:href="#stickman" x="25" y="145"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#stickman" x="85" y="145"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#stickman" x="145" y="145"></use>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71431150/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>